# Why are top/right/bottom/left CSS properties inherited?

Tags: css, positioning

The standards state that the `top`/`right`/`bottom`/`left` CSS properties aren't inherited.

CSS 2.1: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#position-props
CSS Positioning module: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#box-offsets-trbl

But from what I can see (I tested Firefox, Chrome, IE10, and Opera), the implementations *do* inherit these properties.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="transition">Hello World</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
}

#transition {
  position: absolute;
  left: inherit;
  top: inherit;
}
```

Here, the `#transition` element receives its parent's `top`/`left` values.

**Live demo:** http://t.co/aIRuHPAj

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 10):

They *inherit* the `top` and `left` properties because you **explicitly** do so:

```
#transition {
  /* ... */
  left: inherit;
  top: inherit;
}
```

Without these two lines, these properties would not be inherited **implicitly** (inline with the specification). [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dMhMB/1/).

Comment: My head just exploded from the realization of my stupidity `:P`

Comment: No worries. I've been there before. As an aside, I wish `inherit` was a more power value and worked similar to it's behavior in LESS.